# Websphere MQ messages

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I have two general question on Websphere MQ regarding `messageId`:

1) This field can be used to achieve synchronous communication in a queue?
For example in the following source code:

```
MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage(); 
hello_world.writeUTF("Hello World!"); 
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();      
system_default_local_queue.put(hello_world,pmo);  
MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
retrievedMessage.messageId = hello_world.messageId; 
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions(); 
system_default_local_queue.get(retrievedMessage, gmo);
```

The retrieved message will be the exact response for the `hello_world` message and only this message will be retrieved leaving all the other messages in the queue even if there are more aged than this?

2) If this is the case can this be done with two queues?
Example:
Client Side:

```
MQMessage hello_world = new MQMessage(); 
hello_world.writeUTF("Hello World!"); 
MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();      
input_queue.put(hello_world,pmo);  
MQMessage retrievedMessage = new MQMessage();
retrievedMessage.messageId = hello_world.messageId; 
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions(); 
output_queue.get(retrievedMessage, gmo);
```

Server Side:

```
while(true){
MQMessage inMessage= new MQMessage();
input_queue.get(mqMessage ,gmo); 
//actions to get the contents of the inMessage and create proper response
  MQMessage outMessage= new MQMessage();
//write the proper response to outMessage
 outMessage.messageId = inMessage.messageId; 
output_queue.put(outMessage, pmo);
}
```

Comment: Mq_queue is designated as asynchronous by default, on one side is producer --> channel --> consumer, 2nd example would be confortable for data flow if you created two separate channels put_channel and get_channel, but message_flow is still remain unchanged --> asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using "synchronous" the wrong way.  What you describe in #1 above is true - a `GET` by MsgID will retrieve only that one message.  However, this is not a synchronous messaging example.

The general case of the client/server exchange you've outlined is correct.  It is a common pattern that many application instances can use the same reply queue if they always look for messages by ID.  Normally what happens is that the MsgID is copied to the Correlation ID though so instead of initializing the `msgID` on the `retrievedMessage` object, one would expect to see `correlID` initialized instead.  Of course, the behavior is entirely dependent on the server application's behavior and some do copy the request `msgID` to the reply `msgID`.

Just make sure that the GET by `msgID` or `correlID` includes a wait so that a late-arriving message has somewhere to go.  Also with this pattern, it is common that the replies would expire if not picked up within some time frame - such as an hour or two.